# How to add custom action button in React Native(IOS) push notification

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

Currently, I am using this package:

> react-native-ios-notification-actions

But this package is only for IOS. But I need to implement an action button in both android and IOS. So is there any other way in firebase or other library support for it. I already face many issues in the package from the IOS side.